Flying from Reynosa Tamaulipas to Cancun are we required to get a FMM permit
I've heard they are phasing out with that form on some airports

They're phasing out the form, not the FMM. If you're in Mexico as a foreign tourist you should have got one when you entered.

Both places are in Mexico, so an FMM should not be relevant. You should have gotten an FMM (paper or digital) or a stamp in your passport upon entry though.

Ok thank you. Several friends have traveled within these months without it and they haven't been asked for it. But many people say better be safe than sorry.

I believe that they are phasing out the printed forms. However, you will still required to get one online. You can get it and pay for the non-resident tax in the following link:
https://www.inm.gob.mx/spublic/portal/inmex.html
